# Can't get pointers to pointers working in Gambit-C scheme's FFI

Tags: pointers, scheme, ffi, gambit

I'm in the process of wrapping my graphics engine API with Gambit-C and have been successful so far with the FFI. Today I ran into a new problem that I can't easily get past.

I have a structure like this in C:

```
typedef struct render_list_rec
{
    long render_id;
    render_node* node;
    struct render_list_rec* next; 
} render_list;
```

In C, I also have a series of functions that get defined by macros to add common list behaviors. Then end up looking something like this:

```
void render_list_item_add(render_list_item **list, render_list_item* elem);
```

In C, you can have a render_list_item* that is NULL, but can pass it to the first parameter of this function and it will essentially create the head of the list for you.

My problem is that I cannot get this behavior to work in Gambit-C's FFI. I end up creating something like this:

```
(c-define-type render-list* (pointer (struct "render_list_rec")))
(c-define-type render-list** (pointer (pointer (struct "render_list_rec"))))
(define render-list-add-item (c-lambda (render-list** long render-node*) render-list* "render_list_add_item"))
```

When I run this it segfaults. Upon investigation, **___arg1** of the **render-list-add-item** proceedure is **NULL**. No matter what I try, I cannot get a valid (pointer (pointer)) in the FFI.

Is there something I'm missing with this?

============================================================

A complete scheme example:

```
(c-declare #<<c-decl-end
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct test_rec
{
    int i;
} test_rec;

void pointer_test(struct test_rec** in_number)
{
  if (in_number == NULL) {
    fprintf(stdout, "pointer_test is NULL\n");
  }
}

test_rec* new_pointer_test(void)
{
return malloc(sizeof(struct test_rec));
}

c-decl-end
)

(c-define-type test-rec* (pointer (struct "test_rec")))
(define c-pointer-test (c-lambda ((pointer test-rec*)) void "pointer_test"))
(define c-new-pointer-test (c-lambda () test-rec* "new_pointer_test"))
(define test-rec->i-set! (c-lambda (test-rec* int) void "___arg1->i = ___arg2;"))

(display "About to run test with #f ...") (newline)
(define the_false #f)
(c-pointer-test the_false)

(display "About to run test with 1 ...") (newline)
(define number_one (c-new-pointer-test))
(test-rec->i-set! number_one 1)
(c-pointer-test number_one)
```

Compile with:

```
gsc -o test -exe  test.scm
```

Gives output:

```
About to run test with #f ...
pointer_test is NULL
About to run test with 1 ...
*** ERROR IN ##execute-program -- (Argument 1) Can't convert to C pointer
(c-pointer-test '#<|struct test_rec*| #2 0x28d3fc0>)
```

============================================================

**EDIT:**

*Felix: Can you give some examples of how you are invoking render-list-add-item*

The C code for this looks something like this:

```
pg_render_list *ui_render_list = NULL;
pg_render_node *ui_node = pg_font_generate_text_string(app_font, L"Lacunarity:", ui_text_material);
pg_render_list_create_item(&ui_render_list, UI_ID_TEXT, ui_node);
```

Its a list implementation based off of [sglib](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/). When these passed a pointer that points to a null pointer,as above, it creates a new list item as the head of the list so that *ui_render_list will point to it.

The scheme code looked something like this (typed from memory):

```
(define ui-render-list #f)
(letrec ((model-data (pg-model-data-read-binary model-filepath))
          (model-node (pg-render-node-create-fom-model model-data GL_STATIC_DRAW)))
  (pg-render-list-item-add ui-render-list model-data))
```

The hope was to have similar behavior. It appears from looking at the documentation that having a #f in the C API tranlates to NULL, but I thought the (pointer (pointer)) might catch that. Even passing variables that are bound to something always led to a NULL value. I tested this by creating a function in a (c-declare) that simply printed the address of the pointer:

If you want to see my full wrappers in action, you can [look here at this commit](https://bitbucket.org/tbogdala/portableglue/src/90c62eea34bc/common_gambit/portable_glue.scm?at=default)

==========================================

The question of how to get (pointer (pointer)) working still stands. But I think that for quicker results, and better interoperability with other languages, I'm going to rewrite my C list macros to define a list structure that will then contain pointers to the list head/tail as seen in "Mastering Algorithms with C". That way pointer to pointers won't be necessary.

Comment: Can you give some examples of how you are invoking `render-list-add-item`?  In particular I am curious how you set up the memory ahead of time and then take it's address, (analogous to the `&` operator in C)

Comment: Made an edit to the question so I could reply with commented code. Plus I was hitting character limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand, but when you have

```
(define ui-render-list #f)
```

then I would think that the expression:

```
(pg-render-list-item-add ui-render-list model-data)
```

would behave like:

> "invoke `pg-render-list-item-add` with the actual arguments `#f` and whatever `model-data` denotes.

And then the Gambit-C FFI is translating the Scheme value `#f` to the C value `NULL` (i.e. `0`) when it crosses the boundary from Scheme into C.

This is very different from:

> "invoke `pg-render-list-item-add` with *an address* `<addr>` and whatever `model-data` denotes"
>   where `<addr>` meant to be the receiver of the item created by `pg-render-list-item-add`.

The C statement:

```
pg_render_list_create_item(&ui_render_list, UI_ID_TEXT, ui_node);
```

is taking the address of the `ui_render_list` variable (which, for example, may be allocated on the stack), and passing that address in to `pg_render_list_create_item`.  This is *very* different from passing in the value `NULL` as the first argument to `pg_render_list_create_item`, which would look like this:

```
pg_render_list_create_item(ui_render_list, UI_ID_TEXT, ui_node);
```

Note the absence of the ampersand `&`; it is a crucial distinction here.

I have not taken the time yet to try to write your example myself in Gambit-C, but I imagine one way you could accomplish the effect you desire would be to allocate the receiving memory yourself (by hooking into the `malloc` function in the FFI), and then once you have allocated the memory, you will then have an address that you can pass as the first parameter to `pg-render-list-item`.

Comment: That's a good explanation of the problem.

I think allocating a new pointer in the FFI wrapper won't completely solve my problem since I don't see how I could return it through the API unless I return scheme pairs of (<return value>, <new list pointer>).

This it the best answer so far.

Comment: You could keep your hands on the value returned by `malloc` when you call it; that would represent the head of the list from that point onward, as I understand your API.  It depends on what you want: a native list structure that is invisible to Scheme code (what `malloc` plus your API could deliver), or a GUI list structure that is backed by a Scheme list (which would require more contortions, if possible at all).  There have been papers on Scheme FFIs at [Scheme workshop 2008](http://www.schemeworkshop.org/2008/program.html), see session 3; they may explain this more.